# No Fun At All, Again

Tags: riddle, wordplay

They call me play, but I am no fun
Under my civilized veneer
I'm full of Death and destruction
The ultimate in Betrayal, and bad wives too
I wonder why anyone ever comes to
Me knowth that all will end bad
It always does. Yet again and again
As if you don't know how it will end.
March is coming. One ought to know better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that this is about:

> The play Julius Caesar

They call me play, but I am no fun

> This play is a tragedy

Under my civilized veneer
I'm full of Death and destruction

> There is lots of killing and bloodshed in this play, but plays (especially Shakespearian plays) have formal, civilized connotations.

The ultimate in Betrayal,

> Et tu brute!

and bad wives too

> Portia commits suicide, Calpurnia has premonitions about Caesar's betrayal. (the wives of Brutus and Caesar, respectively)

I wonder why anyone ever comes to

Me knowth that all will end bad

It always does. Yet again and again

As if you don't know how it will end.

> This is all about how we go to see plays over and over, but they always end the same way. We know it is a tragedy going in.

March is coming. One aught to know better.

> 'The ides of march' is a famous phrase from the play, which is when Caesar is betrayed and killed.

Comment: The last clue is really the only one that matters.  Without it, the remaining clues could point to any number of works.

Comment: I don't know about y'all, but if my wife has true premonitions about me getting stabbed, I want her to definitely tell me.

Comment: You need to explain "aught." It is used in place of "ought" and does not mean the same thing.